# Chutzpah unable to find reference when coverage is turned on

Tags: javascript, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm having an issue whereby, if the tests are run with coverage off - the tests run fine, no issues. However, as soon as I turn the coverage on I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PushNotificationView

***Test file***

```
/// <reference path="PushNotificationPresenter.js" />

describe("Push-Notification-Presenter-Tests", function() {

    var view = new PushNotificationView();

    /* Some tests go here */

});
```

***PushNotificationView***

```
function PushNotificationView() {
    return {
        /* Some functions */
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I tested locally the issue was your comment that was not close. If I update to the following it worked fine:

***PushNotificationView***

```
function PushNotificationView() {
    return {
        /* Some functions */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah that was a comment for illustration only, not actually in the code

Comment: Can you show a full repro then, Given what you have, it worked fine for me.